# How to continually communicate with a background process in PHP between page views?

Tags: php

Here is what I want to do:
a PHP script(**a.php**) starts a background process from an executable(**p1.exe** written in other languages) which runs for several hours and produces a sequence of output, for example, 1,2,3... 
Subsequent page views of a.php get the output of p1 in order. Because the web server puts restricts on timeout of a PHP script, I have to access a.php repeatedly to read all the outputs of p1. For example, the second PV reads 1,2,3 and the third PV reads 4,5,6.

I tried *popen* to start a background process and read its output, witch worked well. But I don't know how to continue to read in next page views. 
I also found *pcntl_fork*(included in PCNTL extension) and thought I could start p1 in a child process witch continually reads p1 output and stores in $_SESSION for a.php(I'm not sure if this works). But the PCNTL extension is not available on Windows. Media, like via a file should work, but I'm looking for another way.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: write output to file, check file via ajax calls ever X secounds

Comment: **Because the web server puts restricts on timeout of a PHP script** , have you tried `set_time_limit(0)` ?

Comment: "Media, like via a file should work, but I'm looking for another way."

Comment: I'm afraid the web server has a global timeout setting which will override any PHP settings.